# Mockito - Kotlin mock an interface that given a string returns a string

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, testing, mocking, mockito

Let's say I have this

```
interface StringProvider { 
  operator fun get(key: String) : String
}
```

And in tests I've been doing it like this :

```
fun givenAStringProvider(key:String, value:String){
 given(stringProvider[key]).willReturn(value)
}
```

The problem with this is that if I have a method that calls 10 times this interface is a bit mess since i have to call this `givenAStringProvider` 10 times.

Also I've been using this way

```
private val stringProvider = mock {
  on { get("key1") } doAnswer {"Value 1"}
  on { get("key2") } doAnswer {"Value 2"}
  on { get("key3") } doAnswer {"Value 3"}
  on { get("key4") } doAnswer {"Value 4"}
  ....
}
```

And then in the test I get it globally, is there any other way? To avoid repeat givens on each test?

Comment: Why don't you just use a dummy implementation of your interface? There is no need for mockk if you already designed your code with dependency inversion.

Comment: You mean to create a fakeImplementation of my StringProvider and put there the getters?

Comment: Yes I mean create an implementation with an internal `Map` that just returns those values.